# 'Removal of the evil inclination is like removal of the soul'

Tags: sources-mekorot, soul, chazon-ish, evil-inclination

I saw recently ([here](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46224&st=&pgnum=71&hilite=)) in the name of the Chazon Ish that 'removal of the evil inclination removes the soul'. Is there a written source for this (either in the writings of the Chazon Ish or elsewhere)?

Comment: Not  a full answer, but the Tanya seems to suggest that the yetzer hara is in essence the influence of the animal soul, so therefore it would follow that removing the yetzer hara equals removing the soul.

Comment: David supposedly killed his yetzer hara thru fasting. how would that fit in?

Comment: @andrewmh20 Actually, Tanya speaks about a true Tzadik not having a yetzer harah. I don't know Tanya too well, but it'd a seem that the aspect of the animal soul that does bad (as discussed in chapter 6), the Tzadik can get rid of, and the nefesh hachiyunis habahamis, the vitalising animal soul (discussed in chapter 7), which allows us to live, but the permitted things which we do from that soul can be used for G-d or not, so a Tzadik probably does have that, and doesn't have the inclination to use it not for G-d. But I'll look into it a bit more.

Comment: @ray He did. He said in tehillim: and my heart is hollow within me וליבי חלל בקירבי. It's discussed in the first chapter of Tanya, where right afterwards it says but... And quotes that everyone has an animal soul, from which bad stems. So it obviously answers the question later on, I just need to verify if what I said in my previous post is the right answer

Answer (score 1):

see Igrot chazon ish 1 Siman 209

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya.  What does it say?  We're looking for answers, rather than pointers to answers, so could you [edit] in a short summary?  Thanks.

Comment: Welcome, and thanks for sharing this. I hope you stick around and continue sharing your knowledge here.

Comment: I think in this case it is a reasonable answer, as the question asks for a specific source, and this provides it. There is no reason to assume the source says anything different than what the question already stated. Nevertheless, it would be a better answer with a quote.